# Java Regex Find/replace

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

```
aaaa#include(soap1.xml)bbbb #include(soap2.xml)cccc #include(soap2.xml)
```

I want to find all occurrences of `#include([anyfilename])` where `[anyfilename]` varies.

I have the regex `(?<=#include\()(.*?)(?=\)*\))` which matches `[anyfilename]` but then performing a replace using this leaves behind there `#include()`

Can someone suggest show me how to find/replace the entire `#include([anyfilename])`?

Comment: What is the expected result? Please add your current code to the answer. Do you want to remove `#include(soap2.xml)` and `#include(soap1.xml)`?

Comment: "*performing a replace using this leaves behind there `#include()`*" well, look-around mechanisms are [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) (they are not included in match - the one you want to replace) so that behaviour is expected. What else did you expect and why?

Comment: I shared a wrong link :) I will post an answer.

Comment: `\)*\)` is the same as `\)+`, which is clearer on intent. As for that, why match multiple close-parenthesis?

Comment: Right now, the positive look-behind/-ahead will check for *existence*, without being *included*. If you want to include them in the match, just drop the look-behind/-ahead parts. And since your capture group would then equal the entire match, there's no need for capturing. So that would result in: `#include\(.*?\)+` (see [regex101 for result](https://regex101.com/r/kW5hK8/1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
#include\(([^)]*)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV3gH3/1)

I replaced lookarounds (that are zero-width assertions and do not consume text, do not return it in the match value) with *consuming* equivalents.

The regex breakdown:

- `#include\(` - match a sequence of literal symbols `#include(`
- `([^)]*)` - Group 1 (we'll refer to the value inside the group with `matcher.group(1)`) matching zero or more characters other than `)`
- `\)` - match a literal `)`

The same pattern can be used to retrieve the filenames, and remove whole `#include()`s from the input.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/EQUIxi):

```
String str = "aaaa#include(soap1.xml)bbbb#include(soap2.xml)cccc";
String p = "#include\\(([^)]*)\\)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    arr.add(matcher.group(1));       // Get the Group 1 value, file name
}
System.out.println(arr); // => [soap1.xml, soap2.xml]
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(p, "")); // => aaaabbbbcccc
```